# How can i draw an electronic diagram of this?

Tags: arduino-nano

[image: How can i draw a diagram out of this?]

I need help to draw a diagram of this picture
the project include an Arduino nano, dht11 sensor, power module IRF520, 12V power supply and a fan

Comment: You already have done, haven't you?

Comment: Or do you mean a schematic? That can be done by various tools, for example Eagle ir KiCAD (though that is only a small part of their functionality)

Comment: I mean schematic

Comment: Do you want to create a schematic that contains the *contents* of the other modules? Then you need to get the schematics of those modules and copy them, then join them up with lines, just as you have here.

Comment: If you *don't* need the contents of the modules, then the schematic pretty much boils down to a block diagram.  You can do this with Windows Paint, or whatever drawing program you are familiar with... no need for any specialized schematic software with a big learning curve.  Just draw trial sketches with pencil and paper, then when you have the layout you like, create the same in Paint.  Tip: Create a separate Paint image with any symbols you want to use, like upward-pointing power arrow, ground symbol, wire cross. Keep that open and copy/paste into your final drawing.

Comment: It is often the case in professionally done schematics to "block" sub assemblies.  For instance your phone likely contains a GPS receiver and in some cases this is OEM'ed from a different manufacture who doesn't provide a schematic of the insides. Also, schematic capture programs are used to generate PCBs, 3D Board Models and BOMs.  MSPaint can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

See [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28251/2191) on electronics.stackexchange.com.

I'm no expert but perhaps some of what I have found will be of help.

To produce a clear easy-to-read useful schematic it doesn't really matter what tools you use. This website has a reasonable schematic editor so I suggest you could try that to start with.

Other tools I have tried include KiCAD, EasyEDA and Fritzing. KiCAD is maybe a bit hard to start with and Fritzing I find is very troublesome - It's good for the kind of breadboard layout diagram it was originally designed for. I have really enjoyed using EasyEDA. Other notable tools include Eagle. All these are free or have free versions for hobbyists. Beyond that are more capable and sophisticated professional tools.

Drawing a good schematic is an art and taking care of small details makes a big difference to how useful the diagram is.

The main features that I find make schematics for me to read are

- Ground connections at bottom edge of diagram.
- Positive voltage connections at top edge of diagram.
- Left to right flow for signals and power (e.g. battery at left, microprocessor in middle, LEDs, motors etc at right)
- Avoid having wires cross. Adjust the pin positions on an IC symbol to make this possible.
- Label everything clearly but don't let text overlap with anything else.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0RdSj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The way you appear to be powering these modules seems a bit eccentric but this would be how I might draw that as a block-level schematic.